How to log output of script
I want to log the output of my python file into a txt. I also want to still see it in the terminal too.
I tried using sys.stdout, but it did not still have terminal output. To log it I open my log file with f = open("log.txt", "r+"), then set sys.stdout = f. When the code ended, I said f.close() to write changes. Here is some code:
import sys
f = open("files/log.txt", "r+")
sys.stdout = f
print("You will not see this in terminal")
f.close()


Use 'logging' so that you can print as well as log

Do you have to do it in Python? Or could you do it with an appropriate command line running the Python script?

You can set sys.stdout to a file-like object with a write method that writes to both the original sys.stdout and a given file:
import sys

class Tee:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def write(self, text):
        self.orig_stdout.write(text)
        self.file.write(text)

    def start(self):
        self.orig_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self

    def flush(self):
        self.orig_stdout.flush()

    def close(self):
        sys.stdout = self.orig_stdout

    __enter__ = start

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.close()

so that:
with open('test.txt', 'w') as file, Tee(file):
    print('both terminal and file')

print('terminal only')

would output to the terminal:
both terminal and file
terminal only

and output to the file:
both terminal and file

If you mean to redirect the output of an entire program to both the terminal and a file, it would be safer to make sure that the file is properly closed upon the program's termination, normal or not, by registering the file closer as an exit handler with atexit.register.
On the other hand, it isn't necessary to explicitly restore sys.stdout upon exit, since the OS, if not the interpreter, will always do that for you:
import atexit

file = open('test.txt', 'w')
atexit.register(file.close)
Tee(file).start()
print('both terminal and file')


so if I put my entire code in the with open it would log all of it to the file, or is there a better  way to do that.

It's better to close the file explicitly upon the program's exit. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

With the logging module
As CodeMaven42 mentioned, you can use the logging module.
Here is one way to do it based on this other Stack Overflow answer and this documentation sample:
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug('This message should go to the log file')

This will print This message should go to the log file to the console and put DEBUG:__main__:This message should go to the log file in example.log.
With tee
You can also use the tee command, which takes what gets piped into it and then prints it and puts it into a file:
print("Hello world!")

$ python my_script.py | tee somefile.log
Hello world!
$ cat somefile.log
Hello world!


tee isn't just for Linux.

@nocomment TIL; updated.
